# Continuing a statement on the next line WITH A COMMENT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, newline, continuations

If I have a statement in Ruby that I want to continue on the next line, normally I would add a backslash at the end of the line like this:

```
print x \
+ y
```

But if I have comments on the line, it doesn't work:

```
print x #show x 
+ y # show y
```

Is there a way around this?

(Edit: Squeegy's solution is correct and, actually, I knew you could do that but I was wondering particularly whether there is a way to have a comment on the same line as the backslash).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to plus sign on the first line.  I dont think comments work with the blackslash

```
puts 'abc' + #Start abc
  'def'      #Add def
```

Comment: I was actually wondering whether there is a way to have a comment on the same line as the backslash but after seeing beautifulpixel I'll gladly take your word that there isn't :) Thanks.

Comment: Here's why a trailing comment disables the end-of-line backslash.  Lines ending with an operator like + or - need no backslash! http://stackoverflow.com/a/27792546/2097284